# Dual boot Windows after Ubuntu in UEFI. Will Windows recognize my existing ESP partition?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I'm about to install windows on my computer which already has Ubuntu (I am aware that it is usually done the other way around but I only got a windows iso today; I am also aware of the grub situation after installing windows).

I was wondering if windows custom installation will recognize the ESP partition I created for ubuntu? Will windows create its own ESP partition?

Comment: It should recognize your existing ESP. But you must boot in UEFI mode to install in UEFI boot mode. And will need free unallocated space for it to install into. Also make sure you have good backups before any install.

Comment: *In theory* Windows should use the ESP that Ubuntu created. In practice, it sometimes does and sometimes doesn't. If the ESP uses FAT16, the Windows 7 installer, at least, flakes out and won't use it. (I don't know if that's fixed in Windows 8 or 10. ESPs generally use FAT32.) I've seen some reports of Windows mistaking Linux-created FAT ESPs as using NTFS. Ultimately, you'll just have to try it and see. Once you install Windows, you can use [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) to reset Ubuntu's GRUB as the default boot program.